# printing an int[] array with decimal approximations

Tags: java, arrays

How would I return an array of sequence [1/1 , 1/2, 1/3] and so on with decimal approximations with an int[] array? I have tried this so far:

```
public static int[] decimalApproximations (int arraySize) {
    int [] sequence = new int[arraySize];
    for(double i = 1; i <= arraySize; i++) {
        sequence[(int)(i)-1] = (int)(1.0/i);
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

But it still prints 1 for 1/1 and 0 because of the int truncation. Is there a possible way to have decimal approximations in this array?

Comment: That is not possible.  By definition integers cannot store fractional values. You must use `float`, `double` or `BigDecimal` values instead.  Since you don't explain WHY you want to do this we cannot really suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you want `[1.0, 0.5, ....` as your output?

Comment: @bradimus I think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: `int` is for whole numbers and `1/2` is rounded down to 0 when you take the whole portion by casting it. btw `1/1` is always `1` not `0`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, an int array can not store decimal values, but if you want a array with the sequence, this might help:

```
  public double[] decimalApproximations (int arraySize) {
    double [] sequence = new double[arraySize];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        sequence[i] = 1.0/(i+1);
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

Comment: Using java-8, `return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, arraySize).mapToDouble(i -> 1.0/i).toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `int` to `double`:

```
public static double[] decimalApproximations (int arraySize) {
    double[] sequence = new double[arraySize];

    for(double i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        sequence[i] = 1.0/(i+1);
    }

    return sequence;
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to assign values to `result`.